# Datatable select ends in Column not foud exception

Tags: c#, select, datatable

Hi I've a DataTable with 3 columns. They are named "hasid", "sourcetext" and "stringid".

Now I want to get the sourcetext by searching the stringid.

I do it:

```
DataRow[] lang_strings = dataset1.Tables[0].Select("stringid=" + inputstring);
```

inputstring = TeamName_5
the sourcetext I want (and in the row where stringid=TeamName_5 is "Everton".

But I get a Exception "System.Data.EvaluateExcpetion:'Cannot find column [TeamName_5].'"

Why this happens? TeamName_5 is not the columnname in the select-statement or did I something wrong?

Comment: What is value under `inputstring` variable.

Comment: use `DataRow lang_strings = dataset1.Tables[0].Select("stringid='" + inputstring"+'");`

Comment: But that is not the line you're getting the error on is it? It appears to me that you are having trouble specifying how to display the result and are confusing your inputstring value with the column you want. For example, given the information you've supplied, I would think you would get the result using something like `lang_string[0]["sourcetext"].ToString();` to get the sourcetext value from the row(s) that contain `TeamName_5` in the `stringid` column. The `[0]` in this case is the first element of the array, if you expect more rows, a `foreach` would allow you access to all of the rows.

Comment: I tried Raka's line (without the missplaced ") and it works now \o/